Pi Zero Cross Compilation Floating Point Specification
I am trying to cross compile a go project (syzkaller) to target a Pi Zero so it can emulate usb devices. The problem is that I have been unable to find information regarding how to specify the proper floating point flag to ensure compatibility with the Pi Zero. Everything I have tried results in the VMOV assembly instruction being in the binary file and throwing an illegal instruction. My host machine is x86_64 running go1.21.4 and the pi zero is arm6l running go1.21.4. When cross compiling I am using GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5. The makefile I am using can be found here: https://github.com/google/syzkaller/blob/master/Makefile (I am compiling the execprog binary). From my research the GOARM=5 should be forcing software floating point operations, but the information sources are very outdated. I have also tried compiling for armv5 with no success. I also could be using the flag incorrectly since I am not very familiar with GO. Below are the exact compilation arguments for the binary. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.
Must remake target 'execprog'.
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build "-ldflags=-s -w -X github.com/google/syzkaller/prog.\
GitRevision=121701b62358a454bbfdccfadfcce9bb843602d6+ -X 'github.com/google/syzkaller\
/prog.gitRevisionDate=20240605-134717'" "-tags=syz_target syz_os_linux syz_arch_armv6\
 GOARM=5" -o ./bin/linux_arm/syz-execprog github.com/google/syzkaller/tools/syz-execprog


GOARM is expected in the environment; the Makefile has no provision for that, but
export GOARM=5

before the build should do the trick.
Failing that, run
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 go build "-ldflags=-s -w -X github.com/google/syzkaller/prog.\
GitRevision=121701b62358a454bbfdccfadfcce9bb843602d6+ -X 'github.com/google/syzkaller\
/prog.gitRevisionDate=20240605-134717'" "-tags=syz_target syz_os_linux syz_arch_armv6" -o ./bin/linux_arm/syz-execprog github.com/google/syzkaller/tools/syz-execprog

directly.

Thanks, the export worked. Looking back, am I correct in thinking that my injection into the makefile failed because it was specifying GOARM=5 after the build actually took place? If so, how do the -tags function/affect the compilation?

You specified GOARM=5 as an argument to -tags, on the go build command; it didn’t apply after the build, it applied to the build. But GOARM=5 isn’t relevant as a build tag; tags are used to enable or disable parts of a build (e.g. files which are only relevant for Windows).
